# Disable First Column of First Row in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Is there a way (using styles and multi triggers) to always disable the first column of the first row of a `DataGrid` in a WPF control? This is a templated column which shows combo box in edit mode and text box in normal mode. I'd like this to never go into the edit mode (only this column). The rest of the columns in the row should be able to go into the edit mode.

Comment: It would be nice, if you would post relevant code. Please see the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (in other words you want to disable a definite cell), but I would preferable use `ValueConverter` or `CellTemplateSelector` to reach the goal.

In the soution below there is a restriction, that you have to set an `AlternationCount` property for the `DataGrid` to the number of the elements in ItemsSource.
This is a "work around" to get the row index, since `DataGridRow` has no property to get the index(only a method `GetIndex()`).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternationCount="{Binding YourItemsCollection.Count}">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi thanks but in my case this wouldn't work because the target of the style is DataGridCell. As I explained in the question, in my case the Data Grid has templated columns with combo boxes in the edit template. I am looking to disable the first cell of the first row so that it doesn't go into the edit mode at all. The rest cells can go into the edit mode.

Comment: Have you tried to apply posted solution, I.e. copy a `Style.Triggers`?