# Hide specific cell from datagridview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am creating a datagridview in WPF. The column type of grid is **DataGridTemplateColumn**. I want to hide any specific cell from the grid at runtime. How can I achieve it in WPF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable First Column of First Row in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290687/disable-first-column-of-first-row-in-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

Make a style for DataGridCell in which bind Visibility option to data, you want to be invisible and set this style to DataGrid.
To mark a cell to be invisible there are two ways. First, if the cell should be hidden if data in it has some special properties, you can bind Visibility property to cell DataContext with converter, which will analyze the data and return the Visibility. If this is hard or visibility should be set manually, one can make a custom class for a ViewModel, which will contain the actual data and information about cell visibility.

Comment: This will work, if you (can) mark specific cell in ViewModel

Comment: @Rekshino there is always a way to do it, updated an answer to show how.

Comment: There is also a way to do it with XAML only. See linked post.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to hide Column you need to property Visibility

```
Datagrid.Columns[ColumnIndex].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```

Comment: No I dont want to hide the column. I need to hide specific cell or it should be looked like as a blank cell.