# Set background to a single cell in DataGrid from backend using Row-Column index -WPF

Tags: css, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to change the Style(set Background) of a single cell in a Datagrid (lst_DataFromDB) during runtime, using  the Column and Row index values.

I have created a function which takes 2 input parameters (rowNumber and colNumber). But I am facing difficulty targeting a single cell, either the style applies for the entire Column or for all the rows.

Below is my progress so far-

```
private void getCellData(int rowNumber, int colNumber)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lst_DataFromDB.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in lst_DataFromDB.Columns)
                {
                    if (rowNumber == i & colNumber == j)
                    {
                        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)lst_DataFromDB.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                        TextBlock cellContent = column.GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                        string texter = (cellContent.Text); //<--I'm able to fetch the cell text here, so I am targeting the required cell.

                        //METHOD 1:    
                        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("<Style xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" TargetType=\"{x:Type DataGridCell}\"> <Setter Property=\"Background\" Value=\"Red\"></Setter></Style>");
                        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
                        Style style = (Style)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
                        lst_DataFromDB.Columns[j].CellStyle = style; //<-- But, this highlights the entire Column
                        lst_DataFromDB.RowBackground = Brushes.YellowGreen; //<-- But, this highlights all the rows in the grid

                        //METHOD 2:    
                        //***Throws an Error***
                        //column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty,Colors.Red));

                        //METHOD 3:  
                        //***Throws an Error***
                        //((System.Windows.Controls.DataGridBoundColumn)column).ElementStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, Colors.Red));  
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Open for suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about `CellTemplateSelector`?

Comment: You can take a look to the XAML solution for styling __one__ cell. You could then make this in code behind, if needed. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53297078/7713750)

Answer (score 0):

Using DataTrigger would make things easier.You can add IsCustom property
to your ViewModel then check its value in cell DataTrigger.
IsCustom property can be set in your logic side(in this case your for loop)

```
<DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyViewModel.IsCustom}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyViewModel.IsCustom}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```